# ocaml: exposing a printf function in an object's method

Tags: generics, types, printf, ocaml

I have the following (simplified) ocaml code, for a logger:

```
type log_level =
    | Error
    | Warn
    | Info

let ord lvl =
    match lvl with
    | Error -> 50
    | Warn  -> 40
    | Info  -> 30

let current_level = ref (ord Warn)

let logf name lvl =
    let do_log str =
        if (ord lvl) >= !current_level then
            print_endline str
    in
    Printf.ksprintf do_log
```

The logf function can be used with a printf format, as in:

```
logf "func" Warn "testing with string: %s and int: %d" "str" 42;
```

**1) How can I wrap this up in an object, so that `name` is bound?** I tried:

```
class logger (name:string) =
    object (self)
        method logf lvl = logf name lvl
    end
```

(my real logger has a bunch more methods, so it's not as pointless as it looks here. Also, the `name` gets printed depending on the formatter, even though I haven't included that code here)

But I get:

```
The method logf has type
  log_level -> ('a, unit, string, unit) format4 -> 'a
where 'a is unbound
```

This seems reasonable, knowing what I know about the format4 type - it doesn't know what inputs it's going to be receiving. But how come the free function above works just fine? My guess is that the compiler is able to somehow specialize this abstract / unbound type wherever it's used in the case of the function, but not in the case of the class?

**Edit:** I moved part (2) to [ocaml printf function: skip formatting entirely if some condition holds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413684/ocaml-printf-function-skip-formatting-entirely-if-some-condition-holds) so it can be answered independently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1), you can use this:

```
class logger (name: string) =
    object (self)
    method logf : 'a. log_level -> ('a, unit, string, unit) format4 -> 'a =
        fun lvl -> logf name lvl
    end
```

The extra syntax creates a so-called polymorphic method.

Here's a session that shows it working:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.00.1

# #use "opf.ml";;
type log_level = Error | Warn | Info
val ord : log_level -> int = <fun>
val current_level : int ref = {contents = 40}
val logf : 'a -> log_level -> ('b, unit, string, unit) format4 -> 'b = <fun>
class logger :
  string ->
  object
    method logf : log_level -> ('a, unit, string, unit) format4 -> 'a
  end
# let l = new logger "name";;
val l : logger = <obj>
# l#logf Warn "Testing with %d %s" 88 "maybe";;
Testing with 88 maybe
- : unit = ()
#
```

For (2), I think things already work as you would like. No formatting will happen if the level is too low.

Comment: Thanks for the type annotation, that works great. As for #2, it doesn't print anything, but it does do all the unnecessary work of formatting potentially complex values, only to discard the result. If I use an "%a" formatter function that prints to stderr as a side effect, I can see that the formatting is still happening if I use a level lower than Warn.

Comment: I can reproduce your result. Clearly not what I would expect to happen. I'll think about it.

Comment: Thanks :) I've moved the second question to its own thread, since it could get awkward if two different people answered the two parts of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413684/ocaml-printf-function-skip-formatting-entirely-if-some-condition-holds