# ocaml printf function: skip formatting entirely if some condition holds

Tags: printf, ocaml

(extracted from [ocaml: exposing a printf function in an object's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411450/ocaml-exposing-a-printf-function-in-an-objects-method-adding-additional-logic), so it can be answered independently)

I have the following (simplified) ocaml code, for a logger:

```
type log_level =
    | Error
    | Warn
    | Info

let ord lvl =
    match lvl with
    | Error -> 50
    | Warn  -> 40
    | Info  -> 30

let current_level = ref (ord Warn)

let logf name lvl =
    let do_log str =
        if (ord lvl) >= !current_level then
            print_endline str
    in
    Printf.ksprintf do_log
```

The logf function can be used with a printf format, as in:

```
logf "func" Warn "testing with string: %s and int: %d" "str" 42;
```

**Is there any way to achieve the typical logging behaviour of only formatting arguments when they're actually needed?** i.e something like:

```
let logf name lvl <args> =
    if (ord lvl) >= !current_level then
        Printf.printf <args>
```

I'm thinking it's because only the compiler knows how many arguments there will be in a format expression, and I guess there's no such thing as varargs in ocaml? So you can't ever define the *full* body of a printf function, you can only use currying and let the compiler magic figure it out. Is there any way to achieve what I want? Perhaps with `mkprintf`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The continuation functions such as `Printf.kfprintf` are provided specifically to allow format wrappers such as this. It looks something like this:

```
open Printf

type log_level = Error | Warn | Info

let ord = function Error -> 50 | Warn  -> 40 | Info  -> 30

let string_of_lvl = function
  | Error -> "error"
  | Warn -> "warn"
  | Info -> "info"

let current_level = ref (ord Warn)

let printf_with_info name lvl =
  kfprintf fprintf stdout "[<%s>] <%s>: " name (string_of_lvl lvl)

let logf name lvl =
  if ord lvl >= !current_level then match lvl with
   | Error | Warn -> printf
   | Info -> printf_with_info name lvl
  else
    ifprintf stdout
```

Comment: I had used ksprintf before, but hadn't made the mental jump of using something like `kfprintf fprintf` - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to get me some of the way:

```
let logf name lvl =
    if (ord lvl) >= !current_level then
        Printf.fprintf stdout
    else
        Printf.ifprintf stdout
```

I'm surprised, as I thought this might mean !current_level would be evaluated too early (at module load time or something). But changing the current_level at runtime does seem to work correctly. I guess currying isn't pure like in haskell (which makes sense, given the impurity above ;)).

But it restricts me to using the `fprintf` family. I'd prefer to use `ksprintf`, because I also want a formatter, which (depending on log level) may add information like:

```
`[<name>] <level>: <message>`
```

Perhaps I could achieve this by concatenating formats (using `^^`), but I don't see how.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, calling any `Printf.*printf` funciton will parse the format string at runtime. This may change in 4.02. Or you can use some syntax extension for conditional printing.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by "parse the format string at runtime". If it's just parsing, that doesn't bother me too much. I'm more concerned by the effort involved in actually _formatting_ complex objects into a string and then throwing it away. From my experiments, ifprintf seems to avoid doing the formatting, as seen using a "%a" directive with side effects.