# Unintuitive empty formatted string

Tags: format, ocaml

I want to add a listener mechanism to a Format-based logging facility, and I ended up in a situation where my program is typed by OCaml and compiles, but the formatted string just disappeared, and I don't understand exactly why this happens (it's related to formatters returning `unit` when they should return something else, but I expected the program not to type-check in that case).

This comes from a real use case; its simplification may however have led into a somewhat contrived program.

The basic need is this: to devise a `Format.printf`-like function (with variadic arguments) that is easy to use but also allows other formatters to be notified (e.g. duplicating their outputs).

I've been told this is not possible due to typing constraints, and indeed if I further simplify my example below, I do get typing errors, but for some reason the program below does type-check but does not produce the expected result.

```
open Format

let observers : formatter list ref = ref []
let add_observer o : unit =
  observers := o :: !observers

let print_to_fmt (fmt: formatter) (text: ('a, formatter, unit) format) : unit =
  Format.fprintf fmt "<";
  Format.fprintf fmt text;
  Format.fprintf fmt ">@."

let notify text : unit =
  List.iter (fun fmt ->
      Format.printf "MESSAGE: {";
      Format.printf text;
      Format.printf "}@.";
      print_to_fmt fmt text
    ) !observers

let buffer = ref ""
let append text _ _ = buffer := text

let print text =
  let fmt = Format.make_formatter append (fun () -> ()) in
  Format.kfprintf (fun f -> ()) fmt text

let log text =
  notify text;
  print text

let () =
  add_observer (Format.err_formatter);
  log "this works";
  log "this does not %d" 42;
  log "this also works"
```

Any help on how to (1) change the program to display `this does not 42`, or (2) an explanation on why the program type-checks when it seems it shouldn't, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ocaml printf function: skip formatting entirely if some condition holds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413684/ocaml-printf-function-skip-formatting-entirely-if-some-condition-holds)

Comment: As a side note, you might be interested by the [implementation of diagnostic facilities in Gasoline](https://github.com/michipili/gasoline/tree/master/message). Its use is illustrated in examples, if you pick a revision old enough.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do a very strange magic with formatters, that I would classify as an abuse, honestly. Formatter is a formatted channel, not data, so they impose all problems of channels, like non-persistent data that disappear suddenly.

If you want to have a log function, that will dispatch data between registered formatters, then the following will work:

```
open Format

let observers : formatter list ref = ref []
let add_observer o : unit =
  observers := o :: !observers

let notify (text : string) : unit =
  List.iter (fun fmt ->
      fprintf fmt "MESSAGE: {%s}@." text) !observers

let log text = ksprintf notify text

let () =
  add_observer Format.err_formatter;
  log "this works";
  log "this does not %d" 42;
  log "this also works"
```

Will rend the following output:

```
MESSAGE: {this works}
MESSAGE: {this does not 42}
MESSAGE: {this also works}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I may have oversimplified the example; in my original use case, I need the different formatters to use different settings, e.g. margins (one of them outputs to a file, with infinite margin, while the other outputs to a terminal, with 80 chars per line), so I cannot simply create a string and pass it to both formatters.